# Контроллер некорректно реагирует на изменения в фабрике

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Есть некоторое веб-приложение, в котором была создана фабрика для информирования пользователя

```
angular
 .module('app')
 .factory('messages', messages);

function messages() {
    var _data = [];

    function _add(header, body) {
        if (_data == null) _data = [];
        _data.push({ header: header, body: body});
    };

    function _remove(id) {
        _data.splice(id, 1);
    }

    function _read() {
        return _data == null ? [] : _data;
    }

    return {
        add: _add,
        read: _read,
        remove: _remove
    };
}
```

С фабрикой взаимодействуют все основные контроллеры. Результат выводится в базовом шаблоне для всех html-страниц:

```
<div class="container body-content" >
    @RenderBody()

    <div class="push-messages" ng-controller="messagesCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <div class="alert" ng-repeat="message in data()">
            <button type="button" 
                    ng-click="removeAt($index)" 
                    class="close" 
                    data-dissmiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>{{message.header}}</strong> {{message.body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сам `messageCtrl`:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('messagesCtrl', messagesCtrl);

messagesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'messages'];

function messagesCtrl($scope, messages) {

    $scope.data = messages.read;

    $scope.removeAt = messages.remove;

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при добавлении сообщения `a` из некоторого контроллера, в `ng-repeate` контроллера `messagesCtrl` будут отображаться все сообщения, кроме `a`. При последующем добавлении сообщения `b`, `a` добавится внутри `ng-repeate`, но `b` - нет. То есть при добавлении `n`-го сообщения, будут отображаться только `n-1`.
Если вызывать функцию `add` фабрики `messages` внутри контроллера `messagesCtrl`, то не будет такой непонятной задержки, список внутри `ng-repeate` будет обновляться и показывать все сообщения.

---

Иерархия контроллеров в батаранге

[image: Иерархия контроллеров в батаранге]

---

Есть подозрение что оно так себя ведет, т.к список сообщений генерирую внутри мастера страниц (затем тег Asp.net mvc)

---

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mAoAknfhJ78QHcKujsH?p=preview)

При возникновении ошибки внутри `dataSource` контроллера `guideCtrl`, она должна сразу появляться в перечислении`ng-repeat` контроллера `mesCtrl`. Этого не происходит. При нажатии на кнопку update, еще раз пытаемся получить несуществующие данные, генерируется ошибка, мы её не видим, зато появляется старая.

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, чтобы было видно что именно вы делаете, описание словами не совсем понятно. Не совсем понятно каким боком тут `asp.net-mvc` только потому что страница через него выводится?

Comment: В идеале: добавьте [mcve]

Comment: батаранг не используйте иногда он может ломать код так, что при включенном и отключенном плагине - разное поведение. и в принципе он ничего особенного и не показывает. Добавьте больше кода. по вашим словам почти ничего непонятно как это у вас работает и что откуда вы вызываете

Comment: создайте пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) в котором будет воспроизводится ваша проблема

Comment: спасибо, этим сейчас и занимаюсь

Comment: [Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mAoAknfhJ78QHcKujsH?p=preview) - ссылка на проблему

Comment: а откуда файл `angular.kendo.js` - он библиотечный? или самописный?

Comment: `angular.kendo.js` библиотечный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что ангуляр не знает, что что-то обновилось и нужно перерисовать view.

Для исправления можно вызвать функцию [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), например так

```
$scope.$apply(function(){messages.add("Error "+count++, e.xhr.statusText);});
```

**[Исправленный plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHwBHPVwPyndPsErSJgK?p=preview)**

Обычно эта функция вызывается автоматически при пользовательских событиях, например `click`, а так же при ajax запросах с использованием сервиса `$http`, вероятно данная библиотека использует что-то свое, поэтому надо вызывать все вручную.

Comment: большое спасибо, все таки очевидное решение когда удалось локализировать проблему, не смог сообразить)

Comment: @Denis, в большинстве случаев при использовании сторонних библиотек и запаздыванием обновления view именно эта ошибка, что ангуляр просто не знает, что надо перерисовать все

Comment: вы писали что батаранг лучше не использовать, тогда что посоветуете использовать для мониторинга данных внутри контролеров?

Comment: @Denis, `console.log` :-)  например. в нужных местах.

Comment: очень неожиданно ) будем пользоваться значит консолью