# ui-router не отображаются данные из контроллера во вложенной форме

Tags: angularjs

При проектировании web-приложения столкнулся с проблемой: во вложенном маршруте в contract.html не отображается объект. Сам объект успешно валится в логи браузера из контроллера (contract.js) (т.е. приходит). Но не имею доступа к этому объекту в html (contract.html). Может кто подскажет,в чём моя проблема?
Коды app.js, contract.html и contract.js  привожу ниже: 
Кусок кода app.js

```js
    function router($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list/cards-list');

  $stateProvider
   .state('list', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: '/app/app-eng/controllers/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController',
    controllerAs: 'dc'
   })
    .state('list.cards-list', {
     url: '/:cards-list',
     templateUrl: '/app/app-eng/controllers/object-card/cards-list.html',
     controller: 'CardsListController as dc'
    })
    .state('list.contract', {
     url: '/:contract',
     templateUrl: '/app/app-eng/controllers/object-card/contract.html',
     controller: 'ContractController as dc'
    })
```

Код contract.html:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Договор #{{ data.id }}</h3>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <td width="10%" align="right"><strong>№ договора:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><strong>Дата заключения договора:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.cdstart}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><strong>Дата расторжения договора:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.cdend}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><strong>Наименование предприятия:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.tyonames}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><strong>Категория.:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.ccategory}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><strong>Название отдела полиции:</strong></td>
      <td>{{dc.data.rpnames}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Код contract.js

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';

 angular
  .module('hawk.controllers')
  .controller('ContractController', ContractController);

 ContractController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Websocket'];

 function ContractController ($scope, Websocket) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = {};

  init();

  function getContracts (id) {
   //console.log('getContracts-id', id);
   Websocket.getContracts({ id: id }).then(function(data) {
    //console.log('getContracts-data', data);
    vm.data = data.data;
    //console.log('getContracts-vm.data', vm.data);
   });
  }

  function init () {
   $scope.$watch('object.id', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('cc', newValue, oldValue, $scope.object.id);
    getContracts($scope.object.id);
    //getAddress($scope.object.id);
   });
  }
 }
})();
```

Comment: здесь есть куча похожих вопросов про `scope.$apply`

Comment: а что за сервис _Websocket_?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Контроллер некорректно реагирует на изменения в фабрике](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515163/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5)